# LLDB error, what can I do?

Tags: c, xcode, lldb

Using xcode 5.1.1, it shows the message Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACESS(code=1,adress=0x7ffae2c04c48) on the line 'printf("digite o %i horário :",i+1);'

Does someone have any idea about that? I tried to deactivate lldb, but it just didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    struct hora {
        int h;
        int m;
        int s;
    };

    int i, a;

    struct hora lista[i];

    for (i = 0; i<5; ++i) {
        printf("digite o %i horário :",i+1);
        scanf("%i:%i:%i",&lista[i].h,&lista[i].m,&lista[i].s);
    }
    for (a=0; a<5; ++a){
        printf("o horário %i é %i:%i:%i", a+1,lista[a].h,lista[a].m,lista[a].s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` is uninitialized here: `struct hora lista[i];` It has indeterminate value and it leads to *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)., as in the statement

```
 struct hora lista[i];
```

you're using `i` unitialized.

To elaborate, `i` being an automatic storage type local scope variable, it is not initialized implicitly. Unless initialized explicitly, the content of `i` in un-deterministic. Using the value is hence UB.

You may want to change that to

```
 struct hora lista[5];
```

to make it proper.

That said, as a note, `int main()` is not recommended in C standard, use `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` or at least, `int main(void)`.